# spark-submit yarn java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster sqlserver.py --jars sqljdbc42.jar` 
I get Error :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Everything works when I use `--deploy-mode client`  and copy the jar file to /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/sqljdbc42.jar

Should I copy the sqljdbc42.jar to /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/ on all data nodes?

Comment: which version of spark do you use ?

Comment: I am on  spark  2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91 and HDP 2.6.4.0-91

Comment: It worked after  using set("spark.jars","/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/sqljdbc42.jar")